# Is there an infinite sequence of positive integers $a_n$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{a_n}}$ converges and $a_n$ contains arbitrary long arithmetic progressions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is somewhat related to [Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions)

> Is there an infinite sequence of positive integers $a_n$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{a_n}}$ converges and $a_n$ contains arbitrary long arithmetic progressions?

If one allows negative integers a solution is $a_n=(-1)^n n$

Comment: Yes.  Take your favorite arithmetic progression `$\{a_n\}$` and a very fastly growing integer sequence `$\{b_n\}$`.  In succession, add  $b_1$ to all the terms of $a_n$ after the first, add $b_2$ to all the terms after the third, ..., add $b_r$ to all the terms after the $\binom{r+1}{2}$-th.  If $b_n$ is at least (roughly) $n^4$, say $b_n=((n!)!)!$, this should work.

Comment: Actually, you can use a convergent subsequence of the harmonic sequence, where the arithmetic progression starts with something like (nlog(n))^2, the harmonic sum of the progression with n terms and difference 1 will be less than 1/n(log(n))^2.  So the a_i do not have to grow very quickly.  Gerhard "ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.19 

Comment: 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 102, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 100000, 100001,.... 

Comment: @Pietro Thank you, dumb question...